# How to draw edge label on Sigma.js Graph

Tags: javascript, graph, sigma.js

I am creating graph using SIGMA.JS library.
Its getting drawn , but I am unable to draw edge label on the graphs.
I followed and tried to use Github library as mentioned in following thread :

[show edge label in sigma.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401147/show-edge-label-in-sigma-js)

But As Its not much elaborate , I couldn't get through my problem.

I use following sample data in JSON.

{
"edges":
[{"source":"19",
"target":"3",
"id":"abc"}],

"nodes":[
{"label":"a1",
"x":-158,
"y":-171,
"id":"19",
"color":"rgb(49,230,186)",
"size":15},

{"label":"b1",
"x":112,
"y":-98,
"id":"3",
"color":"rgb(138,136,89)",
"size":19}]
};

How can I get this edge label using SIGMA.JS. Is it provided as default feature? If not , What steps can I take to get the same.
If needed, Suggestion on alternative JS library for Graphs is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels.

There is enough info to draw label.

!important: set type as 'canvas' to renderer

Answer (score 0):

Add the "label" key to each edge object.