# Sigma JS - show edge labels

Tags: label, graph-theory, sigma.js

How can we show edge labels on Sigma.js? 
I am aware of [show edge label in sigma.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401147/show-edge-label-in-sigma-js). 
But the code isn't merged yet with the trunk version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401147/show-edge-label-in-sigma-js has the answer

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I show edge labels on graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401147/how-do-i-show-edge-labels-on-graphs)

Answer (score 9):

It's now possible to do this with a new plugin in the sigma repository: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels

Just follow the instructions to build the Sigma project and you'll find this file in the /build/plugins folder: sigma.renderers.edgeLabels.min.js

Include that in your html file:

```
<script src="sigma.min.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.renderers.edgeLabels.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure your edges have a 'label' key defined

```
var data = {
    // specify 'nodes' as well
    edges: [                       
        {                          
            id: "e1",              
            source: "user", 
            target: "b1",        
            label: "This is the label", // <----- define 'label' key for your edges          
        }, 
    ]       
}
```

And then specify your renderer in the Sigma initialization.

```
var s = new sigma({                                                    
    graph: data,                                                       
    renderer: {                                                        
        container: "container",                                        
        type: "canvas"                                                 
    },                                                                 
    settings: {
    }                                                                  
});
```